# A valid provisional profile for this executable was not found

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, certificate

After I created a Provisional for distribution I am getting error:

> A valid provisional profile for this executable was not found.

Why am I getting this error? My XCode version is 4.6. I changed Build settings from debug to release. Any other thing that I might have missed out? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: do you have certificate for this profile on your machine? did you apply this profile in code signing?

Comment: and you have certificate? and this certificate contains key?

Comment: what is meaning of key?

Comment: i'm not sure i can explain it to you, so google the role of the key yourself, but it is 100% that your certificate MUST contain key. otherwise provisioning profile won't be valid

Comment: i can see my provisonal profile is valid in organizer

Comment: well then it must work. check the bundle id

Comment: I double checked.it is correct.still getting same error

Comment: if bundle id is ok, then the only thing that i can suggest you is closing/reopening Xcode or restarting your Mac. It helped me few times

Comment: still same problem.after restarting mac

Comment: try to create a new profile and use it. see what happens

Comment: same error for new provisonal profile.any idea where i am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Basically it could be because of this:

your iphone is not recognized by the provisioning portal

Solution:
1) In Xode:Goto-->Build-->clean all targets.

2) In "Groups & Files" -->Target --> expand it --> right click your app and select Clean "you app"

3) Goto->Window-->Organizer

4) In the Devices tab on the left, select you iphone

5) In the Provisioning section of the selected iphone delete all the current profiles (if any)

6) Plug out your iphone and replug it in.

7) Goto->Window-->Organizer-->right click your iphone -->Add device to provisioning portal

8) Now make sure you have selected the appropriate code signing identity in edit project settings -> build --> code signing

BUild and run ......

Good Luck !!!!